# Bind multiple directories of one drive to multiple directories of another single mounted drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I have SSD and HDD hard drives on server.

> SSD mounted to /
>
> HDD mounted to /mnt/

I have 20 (planning more) sites with 5-20 GB content each.

I want to store

> /home/user/domain1.com/ to SSD
>
> /home/user/domain1.com/wp-content/uploads/ to HDD

And same for other domains

/home/user/domainN.com/ > SSD 
/home/user/domainN.com/wp-content/uploads/ > HDD

How to do it ?

I founded [How do I mount sub-directory to a hard drive in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67038/how-do-i-mount-sub-directory-to-a-hard-drive-in-linux?newreg=8924bede2ad64270aee1301d0e29b905) , but its only for 1 drive/dir. Is there way to make some symlinks or something like this, which points to direct dir on other hard drive?

For example,

> /home/user/domain1.com/wp-content/uploads/ points to /mnt/domain1.com/
>   /home/user/domain20.com/wp-content/uploads/ points to
>   /mnt/domain20.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can make symlinks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't need any "mounting" at all, you can simply symbolic-link the folder like that:

```
for domain in domain1.com domain20.com; do
  mkdir /mnt/$domain
  mv /home/user/$domain/wp-content/uploads/* /mnt/$domain
  rmdir /home/user/$domain/wp-content/uploads/ 
  ln -Ts /mnt/$domain /home/user/$domain/wp-content/uploads/ 
done
```

PS: it is possible to use bind mount also, but it's bit more cumbersome to setup automatically at boot, something like this should work:

```
for domain in domain1.com domain20.com; do
  mkdir /mnt/$domain
  mv /home/user/$domain/wp-content/uploads/* /mnt/$domain
  mount --bind /mnt/$domain /home/user/$domain/wp-content/uploads/
  echo "/mnt/$domain /home/user/$domain/wp-content/uploads/ none bind 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
done
```

Comment: Using ln -Ts will only work until reboot?

Comment: no a link symbolic or hard is like a file, once created it stay here

Comment: About 2nd part of your answer, there is mistake. The right way is mount HDD dirs to SSD, than it works just fine! `mount --bind /mnt/hdd/domainN.com /home/user/domainN.com/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: indeed, i fixed the answer. I would still go for the link personnaly

Comment: please note that with a bind mount you will "hide" the underlying files and folders on the target directory.
Just make sure you have an empty folder you want to bind to.

Comment: yup, that's one of the reason i prefer the link solution, anyway in both case the provided answer take care of moving file before creating the link / bind-mounting